# Есть ли в Node.js способы следить за изменениями в БД в реальном времени?

Tags: node.js, база-данных, sql-server

Есть ли в Node.js способы следить за изменениями в БД в реальном времени?

БД - MSSQL - туда добавляются данные о событиях (от меня не зависят), нужно получать их всякий раз, когда в БД заносятся новые данные.

Comment: Ну вообще-то это не входит в круг обязанностей сервера БД.. Чем не подходит периодический опрос состояния данных?

Comment: Пишу апишку, которая должна отдавать данные с БД, и на фронте бы отображать их автоматически, то есть в бд появилось новое событие и тут же отобразилось на фронте, собираю данные для приложения с разных источников и в одном из них я использовал веб-хуки, в данном случае, видимо, вариант один - периодически опрашивать БД, а как это лучше реализовать, через setInterval? И где, на фронте запросы делать через определенное время или на сервере?

Comment: Покопайтесь тут: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/service-broker/event-notifications?view=sql-server-ver16 Возможно, есть что-то аналогичное и для DML... ну или просто триггеры + UDF.

Comment: @Илья Запросы делать на сервере. Если у вас 50 клиентов, которые утюжат сервер, будет не айс. Можно попробовать посмотеть в сторону очередей(QUEUE) на БД. На таблицу вешаете триггер, по триггеру откидываете сообщение в очередь, что данные изменены, нода получит сообщение и пойдет в БД делать нужный запрос - как один из вариантов

Comment: @Akina (к первому комментарию) а у postgresql есть listen/notify :)